# How can i get Client Webpage cookie information through javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to get the browser cookies information like email or name.

pls help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `document.cookie` object to read the available cookies using javascript.

You can find more details [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html).

One thing you need to keep in mind is you cannot get a cookie which has a different domain than yours.

Comment: `document.cookie` should not be plural.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this..

http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/javascript/cookies.html

Answer (score 0):

Though this [cookie method](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.cookie.js.txt) is in the context of jQuery, the actual JS is regular JS, aside from a jQuery.trim method (which you can a substitution at [crockford's](http://javascript.crockford.com/remedial.html) site.  Overall, it's a good way to set/get/delete cookies.

[This cookie method](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/raw/master/jquery.cookie.js) is also jquery-dependent, especially with the jQuery.extend (whole different story than the jQuery.trim method), but it looks much more succinct than the other cookie method. I haven't personally used this one, so i can't speak much for it.